# Circular dependencies of EventStreams in FRP

Tags: javascript, circular-dependency, frp, bacon.js, ramda.js

*All examples uses `Ramda` as `_` (it's clear what methods do in examples contexts) and `kefir` as `frp` (almost same API as in bacon.js)*

I have a stream, that describes change of position.

```
var xDelta = frp
    .merge([
        up.map(_.multiply(1)),
        down.map(_.multiply(-1))
    ])
    .sampledBy(frp.interval(10, 0))
    .filter();
```

It emits `+1` when I press `UP` key, and `-1` on `DOWN`.

To get position I `scan` this delta

```
var x = xDelta
    .scan(_.add)
    .toProperty(0);
```

That's work as expected. But I want to limit value of `x` from `0` to `1000`.

To solve this problem I found two solution:

1. Change function in `scan`

   ```
   var x = xDelta.scan(function (prev, next) {
       var newPosition = prev + next;
       if (newPosition < 0 && next < 0) {
           return prev;
       }
       if (newPosition > 1000 && next > 0) {
           return prev;
       }
       return newPosition;
   }, 0);
   ```

It looks Ok, but later, as new rules will be introduced, this method will grow. So I mean it doesn't look composable and FRPy.

2. I have `current` position. And `delta`. I want to apply `delta` to `current`, only if `current after applying` will not be out of limits.

   - `current` depends on `delta`
   - `delta` depends on `current after applying`
   - `current after applying` depends on `current`

   So it looks like circular dependency. But I solved it using `flatMap`.

   ```
   var xDelta = frp
       .merge([
           up.map(_.multiply(1)),
           down.map(_.multiply(-1))
       ])
       .sampledBy(frp.interval(10, 0))
       .filter();

   var possibleNewPlace = xDelta
       .flatMap(function (delta) {
           return x
               .take(1)
               .map(_.add(delta));
       });

   var outOfLeftBoundFilter = possibleNewPlace
       .map(_.lte(0))
       .combine(xDelta.map(_.lte(0)), _.or);

   var outOfRightBoundFilter = possibleNewPlace
       .map(_.gte(1000))
       .combine(xDelta.map(_.gte(0)), _.or);

   var outOfBoundFilter = frp
       .combine([
           outOfLeftBoundFilter,
           outOfRightBoundFilter
       ], _.and);

   var x = xDelta
       .filterBy(outOfBoundFilter)
       .scan(_.add)
       .toProperty(0);
   ```

   You can see full code example at [iofjuupasli/capture-the-sheep-frp](https://github.com/iofjuupasli/capture-the-sheep-frp/tree/master)

   And it's working demo [gh-pages](http://iofjuupasli.github.io/capture-the-sheep-frp/)

   It works, but using circular dependencies is probably anti-pattern.

Is there a better way to solve circular dependency in FRP?

## The second more general question

With `Controller` it's possible to read some values from two `Model` and depending on it's values update both of them.

So dependencies looks like:

```
              ---> Model
Controller ---|
              ---> Model
```

With FRP there is no `Controller`. So `Model` value should be declaratively calculated from other `Model`. But what if `Model1` calculating from another `Model2` which is the same, so `Model2` calculates from `Model1`?

```
Model ----->
      <----- Model
```

For example two players with collision detection: both players have `position` and `movement`. And `movement` of first player depends on `position` of second, and vice versa.

I'm still newbie in all this stuff. It's not easy to start think in declarative FRP style after years of imperative coding. Probably I'm missing something.

Comment: Please ask one question per post only. You may [edit] the second out and [ask it as an extra question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: I think it still one question. I wrote _second_, but entirely the same. When I ask question on SO, I want to get general solution of problem. Not only piece of code that solve problem. But also I want to show real example. So you can get what I mean exactly

Comment: Notice you can shorten your `scan` solution a lot like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25755608/1048572)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> using circular dependencies is probably anti-pattern

Yes and no. From the difficulties you had with implementing this, you can see that it's hard to create a circular dependency. Especially in a declarative way. However, if we want to use pure declarative style, we can see that **circular dependencies are invalid**. E.g. in Haskell you can declare `let x = x + 1` - but it will evaluate to an exception.

> `current` depends on `delta`, `delta` depends on `current after applying`,
>   `current after applying` depends on `current`

If you look closely, it doesn't. If this were a true circular dependency, `current` never had any value. Or [threw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17637647/1048572).

Instead, `current` does **depend on its previous state**. This is a well-known pattern in FRP, the **stepper**. Taking from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23013330/1048572):

```
e = ((+) <$> b) <@> einput
b = stepper 0 e
```

Without knowing what `<$>` and `<@>` exactly do, you can probably tell how the events `e` and the behaviour ("property") `b` depend on the events `einput`. And much better, we can declaratively extend them:

```
e = ((+) <$> bound) <@> einput
bound = (min 0) <$> (max 1000) <$> b
b = stepper 0 e
```

This is basically what Bacon does in `scan`. Unfortunately it forces you to do all of this in a single callback function.

I haven't seen a `stepper` function in any JS FRP library<sup>1</sup>. In Bacon and Kefir, you'll probably have to use a `Bus` if you want to implement this pattern. *I'd be happy to be proven wrong :-)*

<sub>[1]: Well, except in the one I have implemented myself because of this (it's not presentable yet). But using `Stepper` still felt like jumping through hoops, as JavaScript doesn't support recursive declarations.</sub>

Comment: `depend on its previous state` here is my mistake. And it answer for the general question. So `ModelOne` depends on `*Previous`, but `*Previous` can't depends on future values. So there is no circular dependencies. From [what is FRP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028250/what-is-functional-reactive-programming) **Dynamic/evolving values (i.e., values "over time") are first class values in themselves.**. So `value` in `time` and `value` in `time+1` is different values. As I understand it. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, exactly. And the program tries to evaluate `value(time+∞)`, starting with `value(time)`. This doesn't work exactly well with JS' async model of time, tough.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new framework/library called  [cyclejs](https://github.com/staltz/cycle) that works off exactly the circular mechanism you describe, but in that case for a webfrontend library similar to Facebook's new React.

The basic idea is to have a Model that is a stream of "state" values, a view stream that renders those, a user-interaction stream that emits the user interactions coming from the sideeffect of the view (the browser DOM) and an "intent" stream that creates high level events from the user and feeds into the model which creates new values.

It's still in early development, but it's a pretty neat idea and works well so far.